# Is there a problem with capture date in Nikon P340?

Tags: nikon, date

I have a P340 and, as far as I'm aware, the date has always been set correctly.
However on New Years eve I shot a number of pictures at a New years party.  Pictures taken from about 7 pm to around 1 am have the date / time increased by one year.   Pictures taken on Jan 2nd and later are all fine.  Has anyone experienced anything similar?

The 7 pm aspect is interesting - that would be midnight GMT I think ...   (Im in Canada on EST).

(Ive posted separately asking how to fix this - the jpg files were easy I just changed them in windows explorer but the raw files are more of a challenge).

Comment: Exiftool modifies metadata of most of RAW files. I cannot describe thew rorkflow so posting it as a comment.